# Xamarin collectionview is not scrolling smoothly

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, collectionview, smooth-scrolling

I am using collection view in Xamarin and I don't know what reason the scrolling is not smooth. I implemented compiled binding and increased the Garbage collector size in android. I would like any recommendation on how to optimize the collection view, or point out what the problem is.

```
<CollectionView x:DataType="viewmodels:PageViewModel"   ItemsSource="{Binding ItemList}" >                     

 <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
   <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:Item">
     <StackLayout>
          <BoxView HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" HeightRequest="5" Color="Silver"/>
          <Grid RowSpacing="0" ColumnSpacing="0" Padding="15,10">
             <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                 <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                 <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                 <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                 <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                 <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                 <RowDefinition Height="40" />
             </Grid.RowDefinitions>
             <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
               <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
               <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
               <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
             </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
             <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Horizontal">
               <ff:CachedImage Source="Image.jpg" HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="50" HorizontalOptions="Start">
                 <ff:CachedImage.Transformations>
                   <ffTrans:CircleTransformation />
                 </ff:CachedImage.Transformations>
                </ff:CachedImage>
                <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Padding="10,0,0,0">
                  <Label Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="Small"/>
                  <Label Text="{Binding Date, StringFormat='{0:dd MMM yyyy}'}"  FontSize="Small"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </StackLayout>

       <ImageButton Grid.Row="0" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Grid.Column="2" IsVisible="True"  Source="Icon.png"  WidthRequest="30"  HorizontalOptions="End">
          <ImageButton.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger TargetType="ImageButton" Binding="{Binding .}" Value="True" >
               <Setter Property="IsVisible" Value="False" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger TargetType="ImageButton" Binding="{Binding .}" Value="False" >
              <Setter Property="IsVisible" Value="False" />
            </DataTrigger>
           </ImageButton.Triggers>
         </ImageButton>
         <ImageButton Grid.Row="0" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Grid.Column="2" IsVisible="False" Source="Icon.png"  WidthRequest="30"  HorizontalOptions="End">
       <ImageButton.Triggers>
         <DataTrigger TargetType="ImageButton" Binding="{Binding .}" Value="True" >
           <Setter Property="IsVisible" Value="True" />
         </DataTrigger>
       </ImageButton.Triggers>
    </ImageButton>
    <ImageButton Grid.Row="0" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Grid.Column="2" IsVisible="False" Source="img.png"   WidthRequest="30"   HorizontalOptions="End">
       <ImageButton.Triggers>
         <DataTrigger TargetType="ImageButton" Binding="{Binding .}" Value="False" >
           <Setter Property="IsVisible" Value="True" />
         </DataTrigger>
       </ImageButton.Triggers>
    </ImageButton>

    <ImageButton Grid.Row="0" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Grid.Column="2" Source="Icon.png"  WidthRequest="20"  HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
       <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Text="{Binding Text}" Margin="0,10"/>
       <mediavideoplayer:VideoPlayer x:Name="mediaelement" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" IsEnabled="{Binding Attachments, Converter={StaticResource VideoVisibilityConverter}}" IsVisible="{Binding Attachments ,Converter={StaticResource VideoVisibilityConverter}}" DisplayControls="False" FillMode="ResizeAspectFill"  HeightRequest="350" AutoPlay="True" Repeat="True">
         <mediavideoplayer:VideoPlayer.Source>
           <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource VideoUrlConverter}">
             <Binding Path="Attachments.Path" />
             <Binding Path="Attachments" />
           </MultiBinding>
         </mediavideoplayer:VideoPlayer.Source>
     </mediavideoplayer:VideoPlayer>
     <Image IsVisible="{Binding Attachments, Converter={StaticResource ImageVisibilityConverter}}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Aspect="AspectFill" Style="{StaticResource StCommentPicture}">
        <Image.Source>
           <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource UrlConverter}">
              <Binding Path="Attachments.path" />
              <Binding Path="Attachments" />
           </MultiBinding>
        </Image.Source>
     </Image>

     <StackLayout Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" >
        <Label Text="&#128077;"  />
        <Label Text="&#x1f60d;"  />
        <Label Text="&#128514;"  />
        <Label x:Name="LikesCount" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding likes}" />
     </StackLayout>

     <Label Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalOptions="End" Text="{Binding Comments, StringFormat='{0} Comments'}" Margin="0,6"/>
     <BoxView Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand" HeightRequest="1" Color="LightGray" Margin ="0,5"/>
     <Frame Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" x:Name="likeArea" Opacity="0" Padding="0"  HasShadow="true" OutlineColor="#EEEEEE" CornerRadius="70">
         <Grid x:Name="GridlikeArea" Padding="5,0" BackgroundColor="Transparent"  ColumnDefinitions="*,*,*,*,*" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
           <Grid.RowDefinitions>
               <RowDefinition Height="35"/>
           </Grid.RowDefinitions>
           <ImageButton x:Uid="Like" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Aspect="AspectFit" Source="Like.png" Clicked="LikeFrame_Clicked" ></ImageButton>
           <ImageButton x:Name="Laugh" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"  Aspect="AspectFit" Source="Laugh.png" Clicked="LikeFrame_Clicked"></ImageButton>
           <ImageButton x:Name="Love" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"  Aspect="AspectFit" Source="love.png" Clicked="LikeFrame_Clicked"></ImageButton>
           <ImageButton x:Name="Sad" BackgroundColor="Transparent"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Aspect="AspectFit" Source="sad.png" Clicked="LikeFrame_Clicked"></ImageButton>
           <ImageButton x:Name="Hate" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="4" Aspect="AspectFit" Source="angry.png" Clicked="LikeFrame_Clicked"></ImageButton>
      </Grid>
   </Frame>
   <Button x:Name="LikeButton" HeightRequest="40" BackgroundColor="{Binding Reactions,Converter={StaticResource ReactionColorConverter}}"
```

CornerRadius="50" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0" ImageSource="{Binding Reactions, Converter={StaticResource ReactionImageConverter}}" Text="Like" Clicked="LikeButton_Clicked"   HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"/>

```
                                </Grid>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <CollectionView.Footer>
                        <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Padding="0">
                            <Button  BackgroundColor="Transparent" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" TextColor="#529dff" FontAttributes="Bold" Text="Load More..." Command="{Binding LoadMoreCommand}" Clicked="loadmorebutton_Clicked"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </CollectionView.Footer>
                </CollectionView>
```

**Note: deleting the mediavideoplayer:VideoPlayer control wont make any difference **

Comment: That is a complicated `ItemTemplate`. With references to urls and ff images. You may need to write code to "cache" everything you are going to reference, *before* showing that page. I also recommend removing everything, and testing smoothness while add items one at a time. Find out whether certain items are especially slow. Bottom line: start googling. And start testing each line of code, to find out where it gets slow. Attempt to write code to improve the situation. Then come back to StackOverflow.

Comment: Also try using fixed (number) row heights, instead of "Auto". That lets "layout" logic assign space directly, instead of after loading the images. Try to get the same layout with fewer uses of "StackLayout" and "Grid". Search for discussions of how to use a single grid to do most layouts. "Grid.RowSpan" and "Grid.ColumnSpan" help with this.

Comment: Would you mind sharing us a baisc, minimal project to test ? You can upload it to github and attach the link here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Issue is solved by the nuget Glidex. glidex.forms is small library we can use to improve Xamarin.Forms image performance on Android by taking a dependency on Glide. See my post on the topic [here](https://github.com/jonathanpeppers/glidex).